# Firebase search nested child's with value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure

```
  101010 --- USER ID
       202020 -- Reuqest ID
           ReqName: Name
           isValid: true
       608080 -- Reuqest ID
           ReqName: Name
           isValid: false
  202020 --- USER ID
       303030 -- Reuqest ID
           ReqName: Name
           isValid: false
```

I want to get a List of all users and requests that isValid=true;

How Can I achieve this? in firebase.

I am using c# Unity firebase SDK.
its fine to have a code with JavaScript or Java.

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database orders/filters child nodes based on a value that is at a known path directly under each child node. So you can filter the requests for a specific user on their `isValid`, but (with your current structure) not across all requests for all users. If you want that, consider storing all user requests in one flat list, with an additional user ID property in each request. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested